# Convert string to unicode view

Tags: python, encoding

I have a string

```
s = "Санкт-Петербург"
```

I want to convert the string to

```
\u0421\u0430\u043D\u043A\u0442-\u041F\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433
```

**My code**

```
x = "Санкт-Петербург"
y = str(x.encode('unicode-escape')) # I want y to be string
print(y) # b'\\u0421\\u0430\\u043d\\u043a\\u0442-\\u041f\\u0435\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433'
```

What is the best way to get rid of `b'` and `\\` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace **4 backslashes** with **2 backslashes** using `replace()` method. After that you can strip away the `b'` at the start and `'` at the end using `strip()` method.

Here's how you can proceed:

```
y = y.replace('\\\\', '\\')    # Replace backslashes
y = y.strip("b'")              # Strip the unnecessary parts

print(y)                       # Print out the result
```

#### Output

---

```
\u0421\u0430\u043D\u043A\u0442-\u041F\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433
```

*PS: `strip("b'")` also strips the end of the string for single quotes.*

#### EDIT

As pointed out by @Aplet123, `strip("b'")` might cause some issues with any string that contains an ASCII `b` or `'` at the start or end. Thus, instead of `strip()`, string slice could be used. All you need to do is replace the line `y = y.strip("b'")` with:

```
y = y[2:][:-1]
```

Here, `2:` will strip away the `b'` at the start and `:-1` will strip away the trailing `'`

Comment: This will yield the wrong result for `x = "banana"` or any string that starts with or ends with `b` or a single quote.

Answer (score 3):

Use a slice of `[2:-1]`, which will slice off the `b'` and the ending `'`, then replace all the `'\'` with `''`. Here is how:

```
x = "Санкт-Петербург"
y = str(x.encode('unicode-escape'))
print(y[2:-1].replace('\\\\', '\\'))
```

Output:

```
\u0421\u0430\u043d\u043a\u0442-\u041f\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433
```